# Why are the positions of my nodes different on every device?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, cgpoint

Ok, so I've been trying to position a line on my iPhone 6s+ and my iPad 2. The line was added in an SKCamera (I don't know if that effects it or not). Here is the code for the line:

```
    var leftWall = SKSpriteNode()
    leftWall.size = CGSize(width: 1, height: 10000)
    leftWall.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    leftWall.color = UIColor.red
    leftWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: leftWall.size.width, height: leftWall.size.height))
    leftWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    leftWall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    leftWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = groundGroup
    leftWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ballGroup
    leftWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    theCamera.addChild(leftWall)
```

Okay, so the x position is 0,0 right? Here is how it looks on my iPhone 6s+:[image: iPhone 6s+]
As you see, the line is in the middle?

Here is how it looks on my iPad 2:

[image: iPad 2]

I just don't understand why the position of the line is completely different.. Please help me!

Comment: It depends on the anchor point of the scene unless that of the node is specifically set.

Comment: @ElTomato I have tried setting the anchor point to 0,0 on it but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: And why do you want to set the anchor point of the node to 0,0?  And what is the anchor point of the scene itself?

Comment: if you can make a minimal project replicating this issue and post it then I will try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You are not taking into account the cropping that happens on the iPad, or your scaleMode is all wrong

What you need to do is set all nodes anchor points (Including the scene) to (0.5,0.5), make sure your GameScene has a static size and not based on view.frame (750,1334 is a good one) and that your scale mode is set to .aspectFill.  This makes (0,0) the center of the screen, and you will notice everything line up on all devices

Comment: Knight0fDragon, everything lines up except for the wall for some reason.

Comment: it seems as if the wall position isnt updating with every device. It always say its x coordinate is 512 on every device

Comment: why wouldn't it say 512 on every device

Comment: How do i check if it has a static size

Comment: by not doing GameScene(view.frame.size)

Comment: Yeah there's a static size. I did what you told me and it doesnt work. The line is only centered on my iPhone 6s+ and not on any other device

Comment: I feel like it has something to do with the SKCamera but I'm not sure how to fix it. This is my first time using an SKCamera

Comment: there is something you are not telling me, because everything I told you would put everything in the center, if it is not in the center, then you did something I do not know about

Comment: I messed around with some things you told me to do and I'm completely lost. Everything is repositioned differently and the nodes don't resize based on device anymore. Could you help me on teamview or something?

Comment: wont be able to for at least a few days,  upload your project somewhere and I will comment it

Comment: Are you sure? I'm sure it will take you like 5-10 minutes. I really have no clue how to fix it and I need to finish this project ASAP.

Comment: well I have multiple jobs and not a lot of free time to be doing some remote desktoping, so yes I am sure

Comment: What should I upload my project to? Do you need to be able to run the app or just see the code?

Comment: I would probably want to run the app to be able to test it,  just use expirebox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148426/discussion-between-josh-schlabach-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: I notice this is still up for bounty, what problems do you still have?

Comment: Nothing works to center everything. Do you have time to help me?

Comment: once you send me your project with the project file I will be able to,  before you upload your file, test to see if you can open it. If you can't open it, then I can't open it.

Comment: Hey did you look at it? I really need the help soon

Comment: send it again,  i didn't look at it and the files are on my work machine

Comment: Sorry man, I work 2 jobs, I will look at it when I get a chance,  Yesterday was the day to get it to me since I took off.

Comment: If you can't provide a project that builds, then I can't help you

Comment: Here is a project that works. https://expirebox.com/download/38b22a2055cc2d1734f8e6e5f9611afa.html

Comment: I don't see a problem. everything is centered

Comment: On the simulator it's centered but when I run it on actual devices it's not

Comment: what iOS is your iPad on

Comment: iPad is on iOS 9

Comment: Then my guess is going to be you are using a default anchor point somewhere and not explicitly setting it,  causing problems,  if I have time I will track it down

Comment: I have been trying to fix it for a month now and I cannot find it. It centers perfectly on my iPhone 6s+ but not on my iPad 2 and iPhone 5

Comment: it centers perfectly on iOS10, not iOS9

Comment: this is because of default values,  in iOS 9, the default anchor point is (0,0)  in iOS 10, it is (0.5,0.5)  Some where in your code, you are not explicitly setting it, so depending on the iOS you are on, the anchor point will vary

Comment: Personally,  I would only support iOS 10 up.  The percentage of users on 9 is too small to worry about

Comment: Idk. I think I will only support iOS 10 if you cannot find the anchor point problem. Do you think you can?

Comment: You can do it if you are in a hurry. Find every sprite, and make sure you set an anchor point

Comment: Ok. I will work at it. If it doesn't work I'll come back to you.

Comment: Do I need to set the SkCamera node to 0.5?

Comment: you have a camera?  I think that is bugged in iOS 9

Comment: Just set the camera to .5,.5,  that may be your problem

Comment: yes they do have them,  I meant set the anchor point to 0,5, 0.5.  You may have to verify if you are on 9 or 10, and actually move your camera halfway onto scene with 9